# bash line concatenation during variable interpolation

Tags: string, bash, newline, variable-assignment

```
$ cat isbndb.sample | wc -l
13
$ var=$(cat isbndb.sample); echo $var | wc -l
1
```

Why is the newline character missing when I assign the string to the variable? How can I keep the newline character from being converted into a space?

I am using bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to quote the variable to preserve the newlines.

```
$ var=$(cat isbndb.sample); echo "$var" | wc -l
```

And `cat` is unnecessary in both cases:

```
$ wc -l < isbndb.sample
$ var=$(< isbndb.sample); echo "$var" | wc -l
```

**Edit:**

Bash normally strips extra trailing newlines from a file when it assigns its contents to a variable. You have to resort to some tricks to preserve them. Try this:

```
IFS='' read -d '' var < isbndb.sample; echo "$var" | wc -l
```

Setting `IFS` to null prevents the file from being split on the newlines and setting the delimiter for `read` to null makes it accept the file until the end of file.

Comment: $var=$(cat isbndb.sample); echo "$var" | wc -l. the output is 12, missing one line, why? 
i using cat to read from file, because in my program it's actually the output of another cmd.

Comment: it seems my last empty line is omitted. how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var=($(< file))
echo ${#var[@]}
```