# How can I add new lines to a string and save it to a file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, tr

I only see spaces, no new lines.

script.sh:

```
STRING=$(echo "alpha,beta,gamma,delta" | tr "," "\n")
echo $STRING > string.txt
```

Result:

```
$ cat string.txt
alpha beta gamma delta
```

Desired result

```
$ cat string.txt
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184358/how-to-avoid-bash-command-substitution-to-remove-the-newline-character

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani Is it really a duplicate of the question you linked?

Comment: If you want to have fun, you can always set `IFS` to nothing as: `IFS=''`. Then it works. Haha. Of course, the answer to your problem is to quote your variables. Use More Quote as some would say.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash line concatenation during variable interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445628/bash-line-concatenation-during-variable-interpolation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try quoting the `$STRING` variable:

```
echo "$STRING" > string.txt
```

e.g:

```
$ STRING=$(echo "alpha,beta,gamma,delta" | tr "," "\n")
$ echo $STRING
alpha beta gamma delta
$ echo "$STRING"
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
$
```

Answer (score 3):

BASH / shell doesn't usually work right without quoting, make sure to use it here to get new lines in your file:

```
echo "$STRING" > string.txt
```

[See official manual on world splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) (Thanks to Glenn)

Comment: A little deeper explanation than "cannot usually work right" would help, perhaps a link to ["Word splitting" in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) -- "The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion *that did not occur within double quotes* for word splitting." (emphasis mine)